# Multidimensional array in Javascript: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an array of strings, but I got an

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

I don't really get why, here is my code.

```
$("#tableLits > tbody > tr input").filter(function(){ return $(this).val() !== '' }).each(function(){
    nom = $(this).attr('name');
    numChambre = parseInt(nom.charAt(nom.length-1));
    taille = nom.slice(nom.charAt(nom.length-2),-2).replace('lit','');          
    chambres[numChambre][nbLits] = taille;              
    nbLits = oldChambre == numChambre ? nbLits++ : 0;
    oldChambre = numChambre;
});
console.log(chambres);
```

The error is on this line:

```
chambres[numChambre][nbLits] = taille;
```

But when I look at the debugger,

- Chambre is an array
- numChambre = 1
- nbLit = 0

My goal is to assign a size of a bed (taille) to a bed number (nbLit) in a given room (chambres)

### Edit

For example, I have this:
lit80n1
lit90n1 
lit120n2
lit160n3

And I want to output something like this:

```
Chambre 1 -> 1 bed : 80cm, 1 bed : 90cm
Chambre 2 -> 1 bed : 120 cm
Chambre 3 -> 1 bed : 160cm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript does not have multi-dimensional arrays. What you can have is an array of arrays, but you have to initialise each "sub-array" explicitly:

```
if (!chambres[numChambre]) {
    chambres[numChambre] = [];
}
chambres[numChambre][nbLits] = taille;
```

Comment: @VisioN: If you want to be explicit, yes (though personally I'd prefer `typeof`). But I think in a controlled environment, this would be sufficient.

Comment: Agree, and let's hope that `chambres[numChambre]` will never become falsy.

Comment: Thansk for the answer. It almost works, the « problem » is that it overwrite my first « nbLit ». So, instead of 4 elements, I have 3 arrays with only one element in the inside.

Comment: @Kai23: The values for `numChambre` and `nbLits` might not be what you expect or this might not be the right approach to create the data structure you want, I don't know. [Read this to learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and inspect your code and variables.

Comment: Just had to do this : nbLits = (oldChambre == numChambre) ? nbLits + 1 : 0;

Answer (score 1):

Before adding elements to the second dimension of the array you need to define it:

```
chambres[numChambre] = [];
chambres[numChambre][nbLits] = taille;
```